# How do I keep a running total for every time the tuition increases and add those values together?

Tags: python, function

## College Cost Estimator

```
def calculateTuitionIncrease(cost, increase, years):  
    #This function calculates the projected tuition increase for each year.  
    counter = 0  
    while counter <= years:  
        increasedCost = (cost)+(cost*increase)  
        return increasedCost

def calculateTotalCost(terms,tuition,creditHours,books,roomAndBoard,scholarships):  
    #This function will calculate the total cost of all your expenses.  
    totalBookCost = (books*terms)  
    totalTuitionCost = (tuition*creditHours)*(terms)  
    totalRoomAndBoard =(roomAndBoard*terms)
    totalCost = (totalBookCost+totalTuitionCost+totalRoomAndBoard)-(scholarships)  
    return totalCost


def main():

    #Variable declaration/initialization
    years = 0
    terms = 0
    numberOfSchools = 0
    
    tuitionCost1 = 0
    tuitionCost2 = 0
    tuitionCost3 = 0
    tuitionCost = 0

    bookCost = 0
    roomAndBoard = 0
    scholarships = 0

    tuitionIncrease = 0
    increasedCost = 0
    
    creditHours = 0
    overallCost = 0

    #User inputs
    years = int(input("Will you be going to school for 2, 4 or 6 years?"))

    #If-statements for if user will be going to multiple schools.
    if years == 4 or years == 6:
        numberOfSchools = int(input("How many schools do you plan on attending during this time?"))

    if numberOfSchools == 2:
        tuitionCost1 = int(input("How much will you be paying per credit hour at the first school you'll be attending?"))
        tuitionCost2 = int(input("How much will you be paying per credit hour at the second school you'll be attending?"))
        tuitionCost = (tuitionCost1+tuitionCost2)/(2) #Finds average tuition between schools & assigns it to a variable

    elif numberOfSchools == 3:
        tuitionCost1 = int(input("How much will you be paying per credit hour at the first school you'll be attending?"))
        tuitionCost2 = int(input("How much will you be paying per credit hour at the second school you'll be attending?"))
        tuitionCost3 = int(input("How much will you be paying per credit hour at the third school you'll be attending?"))
        tuitionCost = (tuitionCost1+tuitionCost2+tuitionCost3)/(3) #Finds average tuition cost between schools & assigns it to a variable

    else:
        tuitionCost = int(input("Please enter how much you will be paying per credit hour."))

    terms = (years*2)

    tuitionIncrease = float(input("Please enter the projected tuition increase per year in percentage form (ex. if increase is 7% enter .07)."))
    creditHours = int(input("On average, how many credit hours will you be receiving per term?"))
    roomAndBoard = int(input("Please enter what your price of room and board will be per term."))
    bookCost = int(input("Please enter what your average book cost will be per term."))
    scholarships = int(input("Please enter the total amount you will be recieving from grants and scholarships."))

    #Calls function that calculates tuition increase
    increasedCost = calculateTuitionIncrease(tuitionCost,tuitionIncrease,years)

    #Calls function that calculates tuition increase
    overallCost = calculateTotalCost(terms,tuitionCost,creditHours,bookCost,roomAndBoard,scholarships)

    print ("Your total estimated college cost is", overallCost)

main()
```

Comment: Please __explain__ a bit more.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to python. I would like the function 'calculateTuitionIncrease' to keep track of the tuition increase each year and then use those values to calculate the total cost.

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a hint at how you might be able to effectively use a loop to gather the cost info. In general, try to separate the user input from your calculations. And separate the text into constants that can be easily changed in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally a running total or running average is something you calculate through several iterations of your code. However, I don't see any loops here.

Perhaps you mean that you'd like a sum of the costs of each school tuition.

In that case, you were almost there when you calculated the average.  Create a variable that can hold the total cost as you get the values back from your functions.

As you get the results back from your function:

```
tuitionTotal = (tuitionCost1+tuitionCost2+tuitionCost3) * tuitionIncrease
```

It seems like you may be able to clean up the logic of your code a little bit as well. I'd suggest asking most of your questions up front, then doing all your calculations afterward.

Something like this might help:

```
tuitionCost = 0
COST_TEXT = "How much will you be paying per credit hour at school number "

...

for i in range(numberOfSchools):
    tuitionCost += int(input(COST_TEXT+str(i+1)+"?"))

...

tuitionAverage = tuitionCost / (i+1)
tuitionTotal = tuitionCost * tuitionIncrease
```